# Using :checked to toggle CSS for an element anywhere on the page?

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have recently heard of a method that uses a checkbox to style an element adjacent to it, using:

```
.checkbox-whatever:checked + .toggling-element{
 Some css
}
```

Now I'd like to do the same thing but with a piece of css being applied globally and not just to the next element. So basically while the checkbox is checked the css will behave as if it was:

```
.toggling-element{
Some css
}
```

Then it will apply to all elements with class "toggling-element", not just an element adjacent to the checkbox.

Is that possible?

Comment: The toggling element has to have some sort of relationship with a checkbox that can be expressed using CSS selectors (no matter how complex), so it's completely dependent on your structure. For example if the toggling element lives somewhere above your checkbox, you won't be able to reach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `.toggle-element` elements aren't all siblings of your `.checkbox-whatever`:

*No*, you can't do this without JavaScript because CSS has no way of selecting parent elements.

I think it's safe to assume you wouldn't structure your markup that way; it'd be far too impractical.

Comment: Well, as long as they're (later) *siblings* within the same parent you could use the general-sibling combinator `~`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to create some workaround now where my elements will all be within the same parent as the checkbox.